# Replica volume id unable to retrieve

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I was trying to retrieve `replica volume id` using filter & softlayer services, but filter does not work.

```
objectFilterstorage = {"iscsiNetworkStorage": {"username": {"operation": storage_name}}}

client [Softlayer_Account].getIscsiNetworkStorage(filter=objectFilterstorage)
```

Here, I need help to get the object filter.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the following using [SoftLayer_Account::getNetworkStorage](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage):

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask[id,username,replicationPartners[id,username]]&objectFilter={   "networkStorage": {     "replicationPartners": {       "username": {         "operation": "MYUSERNAME_REP_1"       }     }   } }

Method:GET
```

Comment: This works for source storage, i want to get exact Id of REPLICA volume. The above one is not giving exact id of replica volume. Thats why i was using;

objectFilterstorage = {"iscsiNetworkStorage": {"username": {"operation": storage_name}}}